# ¿como invalido una sesión en JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

Ya tengo mis formularios de y en mi proyecto java web "JSP" conectado a base de datos oracle 10g, ya es funcionable, me permite ingresar y salir con los usuarios registrados pero tengo un problema:

Cuando le doy en cerrar sesión me redirecciona bien al login para volver a loguearme pero no invalida la sesión, si regreso a las paginas anteriores me las muestra y yo no quiero que las muestre por que la sesión ya debió estar finalizada y no se como invalidarla según mi código permitiría destruir la sesión pero algo anda mal, aquí dejare mi código. Muchas Gracias.   Este es el codigo del login.jsp

```
<%  operaciones op = new operaciones();
if (request.getParameter("btnIngresar") !=null){
    String user_name=request.getParameter("txtUser");
    String nombre=request.getParameter("txtNombre");
    HttpSession sesion = request.getSession();
    switch(op.logear(user_name ,nombre)){
        case 1:


            sesion.setAttribute("user_name", user_name);
            sesion.setAttribute("nivel", "1");
            response.sendRedirect("inicio.jsp");
            out.print("<a href=''><h5>Bienvenido "+user_name+" </h5></a>");
            break;

        case 2:

            sesion.setAttribute("user_name", user_name);
            sesion.setAttribute("nivel", "2");
            response.sendRedirect("user.jsp");
            out.print("<a href='edicion.html?cerrar=false' ><h5>Bienvenido "+user_name+" </h5></a>");

            break;

        default:
            out.write("<center></center>");
            out.write("<center>El usuario no existe o contraseña invalida, intente de nuevo</center>");
            break;

    }

     if (request.getParameter("cerrar")!=null){
    session.invalidate();

}
}
```

%>

Este es el de mi logout.jsp

```
 <% HttpSession sesion = request.getSession();
String user_name;
String nivel;

if (sesion.getAttribute("user_name")!=null && sesion.getAttribute("nivel")!=null){
  user_name=sesion.getAttribute("user_name").toString();
  nivel=sesion.getAttribute("nivel").toString();        
  out.print("<a href='login.jsp?cerrar=true' ><h5>Cerrar sesion "+user_name+" </h5></a>");
}else{
    out.print("<script>location.replace('login.jsp');</script>");

}

%>
```

y por ultimo aqui esta mi funcion loguar en operaciones.java

```
public int logear (String us, String nom) throws SQLException{
Connection conn;
PreparedStatement pst;
ResultSet rs;
int cont=0;
int nivel=0;
String sql ="select nivel from users where user_name='"+us+"' and nombre='"+nom+"'";
try{
 Class.forName(this.driver);
 conn = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, this.uss, this.contra);
 pst= conn.prepareStatement(sql);
 rs= pst.executeQuery();
 while (rs.next()){
     nivel = rs.getInt(1);
 }
 conn.close();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e)   {

}
```

return nivel;

}

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes invalidar la sesion en HTTPServletRequest utilizando el metodo invalidate de la clase HttpSesion

```
request.getSession().invalidate();
```

Esto elimina toda la información almacenada de la sesion como la informacion del usuario que almacenas al hacer login.

Comment: Ya invalide la session como me dijiste pero sigue sin funcionar.
Lo puse exactamente en el logout.jsp, hasta abajo del metodo.

Comment: @MannyBrenes esa es la manera en que invalidas la sesion, ahora el resto depende de como este programando, para que funcione debes validar en todos los JSP que exista la sesion, caso contrario redireccionas a la pagina de login sino hiciste eso no va a funcionar.

Comment: O puedes utilizar filtros donde validas la existencia de la sesion en un solo lado en lugar de colocar esa validacion en los archivos JSP o servlets que tengas

Comment: @calos Muchisimas Gracias, Revisare el código nuevamente y  seguiré tus consejos, te agradezco mucho!